# Variable I need to use in other classes

Tags: php, mysql

The following code connects my database

```
var $connection;

function MySQLDB(){
  $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
  mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

etc etc

This code is within a class called MySQLDB

At the end

```
$database = new MySQLDB;
```

Inside that class I can connect to things using

```
$this->connection
```

How can I access this connection from outside the class within another class?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to the MySQLDB class that returns the connection

```
function GetConnection() {
    return $this->connection;
}
```

then later on:

```
$database = new MySQLDB;
$myconn = $database->GetConnection(); // your connection
```

Comment: Will I be able to use this in other scripts?

Comment: If the scripts include the MySQLDB class, and assuming the connection's been opened, then why not?

Comment: Yeah they do include this file.

Comment: Just having a few problems trying to understand how I want my classes to connect to each other, majorly confused! Thanks for your help!

Comment: By any chance are you using JPmaster77's scripts? THe naming looks really familiar. If so, I would suggest not returning the connection and adding functions to the MySQLDB class to perform all your DB operations and then call the methods that way: $database->DoSomethingWithData();

Comment: Since the connection is public to begin with, you can just do $someObject->connection . No need to add an accessor. Now, if that is a good idea is another question.

Comment: Pinkfloyd I started out using that script but have moved away from it a lot as I have improved. Looking to rewrite a lot of things but the database script is getting out of control. Got 1000s of lines of code in there now, surely that will become slow?

Comment: I guess if you optimize it a bit and make sure that you only deal with the actual database calls from that class and modify the session, form and process classes to perform the necessary function you should be fine. A few years ago I heavily modified his scripts for a project I was doing. I kept everything isolated within their respective classes and I never noticed any performance hits.

Comment: Ok then thanks. I have been creating extra classes for other things but I just get confused as to where to put them. It is good to have someone that has used his scripts. Are they good? How can they be improved? If I call something in the database using $database->thisNow(); , is only that part of the database script used? Or does it load the entire script? That is my concern regarding the script getting too big. It also gets very messsy with 100s of queries within!

Comment: The whole file gets included by the include() statement. But when you call ->thisNow() obviously only that method is loaded. I'm not really too sure on the internals of PHP and how file size can affect things--but I never noticed anything.  I used his login scripts to form the basis for a clothing store website I made as a project in college. I added all the necessary logic for anything a user or admin had to do. it was also a mixture of a facebook like site with comments, pictures and events (hard to explain) and I altered the process class to return xml for ajax calls instead of the default.

Comment: Ahhh i see, sounds great. The way the scripts work interest me. I'm just wondering if its a standard thing to have a process class before a class that actually does the work!

Answer (score 0):

If $connection not marked as private/protected, you can use $connection directly

```
$conn=$database->connection;

$res=mysql_query("SELECT blabla", $conn);
```

or

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT blabla", $database->connection);
```

but better value is to use Singleton pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

Comment: This is what I originally used!